# Ubuntu 18.04 governer keeps switching from performance to powersave

Tags: 18.04, games, performance, cpu, governor

I am facing an issue.I play few games on my laptop such as CS:GO.My specs are **Intel Core i7 8th gen** and an **SSD** and 16GB of RAM.Now the issue is I set my governor to **performance** but it keeps switching back to **powersave**.Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Please edit your question adding what method you use to make the change and what thermal daemons you are running , if any (like thermald or tlp or?). It will also help to know your CPU frequency scaling driver and governor (well, I guess we know the governor). By default it should be intel_pstate. Do `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. Note: I never ever use anything but primitives, but can help that way.

Comment: sorry i am a a bit new to ubuntu dont know much choose ubuntu for development so yeah thats y i dont know much and yes it shows intel_pstate

Comment: How did you set your governor to `performance`? What method did you you use? I do: `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. Then I check with: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: i used few of the commands such as 
1 is this one

sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
echo 'GOVERNOR="performance"' | sudo tee /etc/default/cpufrequtils
sudo systemctl disable ondemand

Comment: to add i noticed something whenever i am playing a game it switches to powersave and if i come out and have a look its back to performance